# Can `showlists` display the page number at the bottom?

Tags: plain-tex

In Plain TeX, the canonical `showlists` primitive is extremely useful for understanding what's going on under the hood.

However, I haven't been able to get it to display the page number Plain TeX puts at the bottom of the page. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I simply append `\showlists` to the `\footline`

```
\footline=\expandafter{\the\footline\showlists}
Hello World!
\bye
```

I get in the log

```
### restricted horizontal mode entered at line 3
\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil minus 1.0fil
\tenrm 1
\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil minus 1.0fil
spacefactor 1000
```

Comment: Ah! That's what the OP meant. +1 (I'll delete my comment under the question asking for clarification)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm not sure whether that is what OP meant, but that's how I understood it.